# Laravel new version/upgrade for my custom application

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel 4.2 application and it in production environment.
Sometime i have bug fixes or updates for it in the local edition, I want to know how do i move these changes from local to production.

Replacing just the file/class that was changed doesn't work. I tried replacing just the controller file but it doesn't work.

Does Laravel compile the code somewhere that i need to upload to production server, What all do i need to change/upload in production to reflect the changes?

Comment: No Laravel doesn't pre-compile or cache your controllers. What exactly did you change?

Comment: I think i made some other mistake, Thanks for helping me understand how Laravel compiling works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, PHP is not a compiled language, so changed and uploaded files will work without any special process. Laravel is just PHP, so it follows the same rules.

However, Laravel uses an autoloader that keeps track of all of your classes. When you add a new class, you need to tell the autoloader that it exists by running:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

This will scan the available classes and update the autoloader list.

If the problem persists after you run `composer dump-autoload`, or if you did not add any new classes, there are three potential problems to consider:

1. Did you upload the files correctly?

Log onto the production server and look at the timestamp of the uploaded files. Do they match your expectation? Consider opening the files in production to see if they contain your latest changes.

2. Do you have a caching or compiling system in place?

While PHP is not compiled by default, there are tools available that allow you to compile it, and other tools that allow you to cache the output of the scripts. Ask your server administrator if any of these tools are being used.

3. Do your changes perform as expected?

Finally, check to see if your changes are in production, but not operating in the way that you expect.

Comment: Lets say i add a new class locally & run dump-autoload locally, beyond adding this class file to production do i need to copy something else also?

Comment: You will need to either run `composer dump-autoload` in production, or upload the file generated by the command. The generated files can be found in the `vendor/composer/` directory.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins I think `vendor/autoload.php` is needed too isn't it?

Comment: @lukasgeiter If it is, I wasn't aware. My understanding is that vendor/autoload.php is part of the mechanism that creates the cached list of classes, but does not contain any data itself. Does it get updated?

Comment: Yes it does get updated. It contains `ComposerAutoloaderInite710218d02c991613a05ce2608c8da87::getLoader();` And the hash part gets changed when you run `composer dump-autoload` It references the class in `autoload_real.php`

Comment: @lukasgeiter Good to know. Thank you for the additional information! Given the number of places that need to be updated, it seems that running `composer dump-autoload` in production is a cleaner approach than attempting to upload each of the modified files manually.